# MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction... error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I have a ASP.NET MVC app on a Windows Server (20**08** R2) and its database is another Windows Server (20**12** R2). When I create a user in my app, I encounter the following error:

*The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers.*

Actually I had encountered similar error and fixed it before, but this time I have not fix although I have followed all of the steps and suggestions on the following and lots of similar pages:

[How to configure DTC on Windows 2008](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2008/)

[MVC 3 : The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346367/mvc-3-the-msdtc-transaction-manager-was-unable-to-pull-the-transaction-from-th)

I have applied the settings as shown on the images on application and database server, but still no changes:

[image: DTC Settings]

[image: Allowed Apps Settings]

[image: Firewall Settings]

I also add the following host entry to the hosts file in the app server:

Is there anything that I can check in order to fix the problem?